# Oracle APEX: Built-in User Group Variable

Tags: oracle-apex, bind-variables

I was wondering if there is a variable like `:APP_USER`, but instead of the username it should return the user group, so I can check if the current user is administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [APEX_UTIL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_UTIL.htm#AEAPI101) package contains some functions that can be useful for this too:

> CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP This function returns a Boolean result based on
>   whether the current user is a member of the specified group. You can
>   use the group name or group ID to identify the group.
>
> GET_GROUPS_USER_BELONGS_TO  This function returns a comma then a space
>   separated list of group names to which the named user is a member.

Comment: That's even better than my solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
SELECT group_name
FROM   wwv_flow_group_users
WHERE  user_id = (SELECT   user_id
                  FROM     wwv_flow_users
                  WHERE    user_name ='MRITTMAN')
```

This lists all group names the user "MRITTMAN" is assigned to.